# multiple ajax get requests 1 script

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to solve an issue where the below ajax request needs to be used multiple time to retrieve different parts of info from the same MySQL table for example select customers that are active and select customers that are inactive.

How can i get the below code to execute 2 different tasks select active customer display that in 1 div and select inactive and display in another div?

```
    <script>
    function webapp_get_customers(){
       $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '/get.php=?status=active',
       dataType: 'html'
      }).done(function( data ) {
      $('#webapp_get_customers').html(data);
      });
    }   
    webapp_get_customers();
    </script>

    <div id='webapp_get_customers'></div>
```

I'm completely new to ajax and have a basic understanding so please go easy

Comment: Look at the ajax `data` property (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <script>
    function webapp_get_customers(status, id){
       $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '/get.php=?status='+status,
       dataType: 'html'
      }).done(function( data ) {
      $('#' + id ).html(data);
      });
    }   
    webapp_get_customers('active', 'active_customers');
    webapp_get_customers('inactive', 'inactive_customers');
    </script>

    <div id='webapp_get_customers'>
     <div id="active_customers"></div>
     <div id="inactive_customers"></div>  
   </div>
```

Comment: this is perfect and is exactly what i am chasing also easy to understand how it works thank you so much

Comment: is it possible to return a value in anything other than a div for example a paragraph <p>

Comment: yes it is possible just use id like <div id="show"></div>, <p id="show" ></p> etc or class like <div class="show"></div>, <p class="show" ></p>

Answer (score 0):

You have to write two different query for active and inactive customer into your ajax file and stored into two different **div**.Like active customer div have "**active_customer**" class and inactive customer div have "**inactive_customer**" class.

then you have to use ajax **done** method. for example :

```
$.ajax({
        url : "your ajax file url",
            data: {c_id:c_id}
        }).done(function(data){
             var $response=$(data);
             var c1 = $response.filter('.active_customers').text(); //for getting active customer data form ajax file to variable
             var c2 = $response.filter('.inactive_customers').text(); //for getting inactive customer data form ajax file to variable

             $('#active_customers').html(c1); // assign data to you div 
             $('#inactive_customers').html(c2); // assign data to you div 
         });


 <div id='active_customers'></div>
 <div id='inactive_customers'></div>
```